# Constructor with non-DI and DI parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'm creating a service that requires some config parameters and a logger.  Here is the constructor for my service:

```
public StorageProvider(string directory, ILogger<StorageProvider> logger)
```

I just added the logger.  I used to initalize it like this in my startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IStorageProvider>(
    new StorageProvider(Configuration["TempStorage.Path"]));
```

The `directory` parameter comes from the config file, and the logger gets DI'ed.  How do I setup my `IStorageProvider`?

Comment: How did you register the `ILogger`? Is that also a singleton? If so, pass that same instance to the `ILogger` registration to the `StorageProvider` construction.

Comment: The logger get included when you do this: WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: You could use `IOptions<StorageProviderOptions>` to inject the directory path.

Comment: Read up on using configurations in documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#using-options-and-configuration-objects

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you exactly, but just to be clear: `ILogger<StorageProvider>` does not need an actual instance of `StorageProvider`, if that's what you're thinking. The type param is for distinguishing log entries, it doesn't actually *do* anything with it.

Comment: In other words, with `ILogger<StorageProvider>`, what you log will be prefixed with a string, something along the lines of "Namespace.To.StorageProvider[1]".

Comment: Note that you should **never** use `IOptions<T>` in your application components, as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore#working-with-ioption-t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the following:

- Wrap the configuration value `TempStorage:Path` into its own configuration class, e.g. `StorageProviderSettings`.
- Let `StorageProvider` depend upon that new configuration class.
- Register that configuration class as singleton into the ASP.NET configuration system.

Example:

```
public sealed class StorageProviderSettings
{
    public readonly string TempStoragePath;

    public StorageProviderSettings(string tempStoragePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempStoragePath))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(tempStoragePath));
        this.TempStoragePath = tempStoragePath;
    }
}

public sealed class StorageProvider : IStorageProvider
{
    public StorageProvider(
        StorageProviderSettings settings, ILogger<StorageProvider> logger)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// Registration
services.AddSingleton(new StorageProviderSettings(Configuration["TempStorage.Path"]));
services.AddSingleton<IStorageProvider, StorageProvider>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Options` pattern as Tratcher suggests in a comment. Read more in the [official docs on Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#using-options-and-configuration-objects).

Basically you define a class to be hold the value you need:

```
public class StorageProviderOptions
{
    public string TempStoragePath { get; set; }
}
```

Then in `ConfigureServices` you register the type:

```
services.Configure<StorageProviderOptions>();
```

In your code, you request `IOptions<StorageProviderOptions>` and set this to an instance of `StorageProviderOptions`:

```
public class SomeController
{
    private readonly StorageProviderOptions _options;

    public SomeController(IOptions<StorageProviderOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }
}
```

Finally, make sure you have an element in your configuration source that matches the `TempStoragePath` name. Alternately, you can register the option in `ConfigureServices` using code:

```
services.Configure<ServiceProviderOptions>(o => o.TempStoragePath = "temp");
```

Comment: As explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html#working-with-ioption-t) the injection of `IOptions<T>` into application components is a bad idea.

Comment: Interesting - I had not read that. Having done so, I'm inclined to agree with that article's assessment (though for now IOptions<T> remains the documented MSFT solution to this problem).

Comment: but as we all know, the fact that Microsoft documents something (or even builds something) doesn't make it immediately a good solution :)

Comment: Indeed, that's true. :)